# Line2D costum legend only one point

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to make a costum legend in a `Basemap` plot so was considering using `Line2D`. It works ok, but I want that the legend only consist of one marker and no line, instead of a line between two markers (see below).

[image]

Here is the most important part of the code I use to plot this costum legend:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
legend_elements = [Line2D([0],[0],marker='o',markersize=10,color='green',label='Label1'),
                   Line2D([0],[0],marker='s',markersize=12,color='red',label='Label2')]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements,loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

use `numpoints=` in the `legend()` call to control the number of points shown for a `Line2D` object. A line is still shown though. If you want to remove the line, set its width to 0 when creating the Line2D.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
legend_elements = [Line2D([0],[0],marker='o',markersize=10,color='green',label='Label1', lw=0),
                   Line2D([0],[0],marker='s',markersize=12,color='red',label='Label2', lw=0)]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements,loc=2, numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```